# How do I add the rotation, scale and translation of my object to my vertex in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to get a vertex and store it in a variable. Then I want to keep updating the position, rotation and translation. Ik know I can just add up the position of the object to the position of the vertex to get the new vertex position. But I don't know how to do this with the scale and rotation. Does anyone know?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FollowVertex : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform testSphere;
    public Transform indicator;

    void Update()
    {
        indicator.position = GetVertex();
    }

    Vector3 GetVertex()
    {
        Mesh TMesh = testSphere.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        Vector3 Tvertex = TMesh.vertices[1];

        return Tvertex + testSphere.position ; // + the rotation, scale and translation of "testSphere"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:**

I think I can modify this RotateAround funtion for the rotation.

```
function RotateVertexAround(center: Vector3, axis: Vector3, angle: float){
    var pos: Vector3 = transform.position;
    var rot: Quaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis); // get the desired rotation
    var dir: Vector3 = pos - center; // find current direction relative to center
    dir = rot * dir; // rotate the direction
    transform.position = center + dir; // define new position
    // rotate object to keep looking at the center:
    var myRot: Quaternion = transform.rotation;
    transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Inverse(myRot) * rot * myRot;
}
```

Now the Only thing I need to know is how to do the scale, can I do that with a matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do that via the [`TransformPoint()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) method, which transforms a vertex from local to world space.

i.e.

```
Vector3 GetVertex()
{
    Mesh TMesh = testSphere.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    Vector3 Tvertex = TMesh.vertices[1];

    return testSphere.TransformPoint(Tvertex);
}
```

Comment: It is testSphere.TransformPoint(Tvertex), and thanks that helped me out big time!